# backdrop-filter: blur effect without using backdrop?

Tags: css, webkit, blur

i want make a div that can blur everything beneath it without using backdrop.
how to make `backdrop-filter:blur` effect without using backdrop?
because `backdrop-filter:blur` not work in all browser

Answer (score -2):

Add a layer above your content 
and set it to

```
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
filter: blur(5px);
```

Comment: This does not work as expected.